# How to pass the global object from NodeJS to a view and access the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the `global` object in Node.js/Express to set some application-wide variables that I need to use in my views. The problem is that it does not look like JSON data I am used to and I am unsure how to access the variables in the `global` object from a view.

This is my `global` object when doing `console.log(global)`:

```
    Object [global] {
  global: [Circular],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] { [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function] },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function]
  },
  MYDB_Config: {                  // sql server config
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'MyDB',
    options: { trustedConnection: true }
  },
  MSSQL_MYDB: ConnectionPool {    // sql server connectionPool
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _connected: false,
    _connecting: false,
    _healthy: false,
    config: {
      server: 'localhost',
      database: 'MYDB',
      options: [Object],
      port: 1433,
      stream: false,
      parseJSON: false,
      requestTimeout: 15000
    },
    pool: null
  },
  ContentURL: 'https://static.domain.ext',    // my global variables to use in a view
  S3URL: 'https://s3.amazon.com',
  RootPath: 'F:\\Project\\Web\\NodeJS'
}
```

I am passing `global` to my view like this:

```
res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Homepage', data, global});
```

In my view (Handlebars) how do I access the `ContentURL` value from `global`? Doing this does nothing:

```
{{global.ContentURL}}
```

If I just do the following in my view:

```
{{global}}
```

Then I get `[object global]` printed on the webpage.

I think I have to convert the `global` object to JSON, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to do it. Any pointers really appreciated :)

Comment: Instead of doing `res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Homepage', data, global});` why don't you just do `res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Homepage', data, contentURL: global.ContentURL});` See if that works

Comment: @isick because i need all the global variables not just ContentURL. ContentURL is just one of them. In my view later I might need another global variable which I haven't added yet.

Comment: If you're expecting to put every view variable into global to use in your views, you are making a grave mistake. Not only are you polluting the global name space, you're also undermining the entire purpose of the data object argument in `res.render` function. If you want to have the same variables accessible in a view, you should create a wrapper for your render call that injects those variables

Comment: @isick can you post an answer with a code example please?

Comment: can you try this `{{@global.ContentURL}}`, Also global name may cause conflict. Try assigning a different property name `res.render('index', {pagetitle: 'Homepage',myGlobal:global, data})`

Comment: @Eldar simply doing `globalvars: global` worked! So when I do `{{globalvars.ContentURL}}' it showed up in my view (didn't need the `@`). Looks like the `global` keyword caused the conflict! If you want to post it as an answer I can vote it.

Answer (score 1):

You should only pass those variables needed in the view, to the view. Polluting the global namespace is a bad idea. If you have variables you want to use in *all/most* views, Consider doing the following instead:

`renderHelper.js`:

```js
const renderHelper = function(res, template, params) {
    params = params || {}
    return res.render(template, {
        ContentUrl: 'something, not a property of global', 
        /* other 'global' variables */
        ...params
    })
}

module.exports = renderHelper
```

when rendering:

```js
renderHelper(res, 'index', {pagetitle: 'Homepage', data});
```

What this does is allow you to pass view-specific variables to the template and still have application wide variables accessible to all views. This is a more semantic approach because you can immediately tell what view variables will be present (not hidden within some global object) and therefore aren't relying on code outside of the render cycle to declare them.

Comment: thank you thats quite helpful. they really are just global const variables that will never need to be changed. I used to do this kind of thing in ColdFusion where you have Application-scope variables for resuse e.g. `<cfset Application.ContentURL = "http://content.com" />` and use that wherever you want. I'm not sure what "polluting" the global namespace means... do you mean too many variables in global?

Comment: I'm kind of overloading the phrase (which specifically applies to the context a variable is declared in and maybe makes more sense for javascript run in the browser), but the heart of the idea is you don't want to risk overwriting a variable in one file that is needed in another. If all your modules are reading and writing to global, you run the risk of accidentally overwriting a property and injecting a bug that becomes very hard to track down.